# Извлечь image из MultipartFile

Tags: java, fileupload, filestream, multipartfile

Не подскажите как можно извлечь изображение которое храниться в MultipartFile?

Answer (score 2):

вот так оказывается можно

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(multipartFile.getInputStream());
            File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png"));
```